# Start over. Zero out reputations on this forum

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I propose that this forum's reputation scores be zeroed out. SE could still post your old reps so that you could use it to apply for jobs, but we could start over in terms of leadership and moderation. The only people who support the leadership here, are the leaders themselves. They are entrenched and obviously value their own personal territories over the community. You can prove this to yourself in 5 minutes at any WordPress gathering / meetup. SE EXECS: YOU CAN PROVE THIS TO YOURSELF IN 5 MINUTES.

So my question is, who would have the authority to do this, besides the entrenched people here? What is that person's email address or telephone number? How much money would it take to force the issue? How much more valuable would this property be if WordPress people actually LIKED it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never heard of or seen any Stack Exchange website where the entire userbase reputation had been reset to zero. That being said, you could bring up this proposition to the [Stack Exchange Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). I believe it would fall under topic there but please read their help section just in case:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Additionally, we just had a [moderator election](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4568/2019-community-moderator-election) which was pretty well advertised, entirely open to the public, and community voted. Every couple years* there is an election for moderators.

** More or less*

Comment: Thank you. I will do exactly that. Obviously the moderator election process is broken, so that's a waste of time, but thank you. This isn't a utopian democracy. This is a website forum. We can just make a case to the people who own it to run it differently.

Comment: Well, StackExchange is quite different than a general forum. It's not comparable to say, The Official WordPreas Forums where you're free to ask anything in any way. Stackexchange runs on a QA model. A better explanation of that can be found on MetaSE which may be worth a read.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164981/322985.

Comment: Another difference that you guys don't care about, but SOMEONE does.... SE WordPress has gone DOWN in terms of engagement, Quora WordPress has gone UP. That's a major difference. I'm trying to find out which people care about that. It won't be the entrenched volunteers wo protect their territory, or who have profited from this current system.

Comment: I understand your point but I do think everyone here cares about the community. It's true, we all are volunteers here. This is something we maintain during off-hours and none of the WPSE users, maintainers, or moderators profit. If you have ideas on how we can increase user engagement while keeping quality content you can certainly make a meta post expanding on your ideas. At which point the community can post constructive feedback as answers.